# How to call a javascript function when a dialog is shown?

Tags: javascript, primefaces, xhtml

Here is my code: dcNewForm.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:composition>
    <h:panelGrid id="dcNewView">
            <h:outputText value="Address" styleClass="arianeDialogLabel"/>
            <p:inputTextarea id="newDCaddress" styleClass="arianeDialogInputTitle" label="Description" required="true" autoResize="false" style="resize:none" value="#{datacenterNewController.address}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <script type="application/javascript">
        var addresstxtarea = document.getElementById("createDCDialogForm:newDCaddress");
        function initialize() {
             // body
        }
        window.onload = function(){
            initialize();
        }
    </script>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
    <p:dialog header="Create a new datacenter" widgetVar="dcCreateDialog">
      <h:form id="createDCDialogForm">
        <ui:insert name="createDatacenter" >
          <ui:include src="/templates/dcNewForm.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
        <p:commandButton value="Save this datacenter" oncomplete="dcCreateDialog.hide();"/>
      </h:form>
   </p:dialog>
<html>
```

Right now I am calling initialize method on window.onload. But When I call for the same dialog to create from another dialog I get the TypeError : a is null. 
As I understood that initialize() is getting called but unable to get the document.ElementById(blahblah). so I want to call initialize method only when the panelGrid is loaded or dialog is created. How to achieve this?

Comment: Shouldn't your subject/title be _How to call a javascript function on an onload event?_ and you talk about onload... from the document? Because that is what all the answers are about, but I think you want to have it on the displaying of a panel or dialog?

Comment: Yes right. I need to call javascript method only when dialog is created.

Comment: Pleasecreate a minimalistic example, without all the google maps stuff, just a plain simple mcve usecase, see [ask]

Comment: Then your subject should even be _How can I call javascript when a dialog is shown_ please correct that (to not confuse all pure javascript devotees)

Answer (score 2):

For a dialog, use the onShow attribute as can be seen in the PrimeFaces documentation

```
<p:dialog ... onShow="initialize()" ...>
```

The panel has no such attibute afaik

Comment: Sorry I am not expert in this stuff but dialog is getting instantiated from another file. How do I call initialize method.

Comment: See my other comment on an mcve. You post code, we comment on it

Comment: Code posted. In second code snippet I am instantiating dialog. My question is How to call initialize method in second snippet whereas initialize() defined in dcNewFrom.xhtml.

Comment: JSF just combines all these files into one and sends it as one response to the client. Javascript is executed on the client so it does not make any difference that on the server it is in a differnt file

Comment: Remarkable downvote... I get the impression there are downvotes by people I downvoted to AND commented on 'why'

Comment: Exactly what I needed, in my case I needed to initialize a video element only when the p:dialog (in JSF) was shown, to reference the right elements (because they can be recreated/replaced every time the dialog is shown: see [this post](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=6569)). In my case, in fact, the event at the document load was not helpful: this attribute did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Use document.onLoad or body.onLoad. Window.onLoad call before the document is ready.

Comment: Not in line with what was asked

Comment: In this code, OP call window.onload = function() and receives error. If use document.onload instead window.onload the problem will be solved.

Comment: Well, partly. Due to limited knowledge of the English language it is formulated kind of hmmm.... OP states it is now done on window.onload, but if OP does the same for/with/on Dialog there is an error. Yes, document.onload is better since everything is loaded, but on the last sentence OP writes that it should onlybe called when dialog is shown

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use jQuery (which has it's `$( document ).ready()`) you can do that:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    myInitializeFunction();
});

function myInitializeFunction() {
     // do what you want to do
}
```

The browser fires the "DOMContentLoaded" event as soon as all the html is loaded and parsed.

The jQuery-Version could be found [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: Not in line with what was asked